# "high school" in UK/BrE?

Tags: american-english, british-english

I was under the impression, that *high school* is typical AmE while in UK *secondary school* was used. However, I was confronted that in British English *high school* is also used, and I was provided with this link www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/high-school as confirmation.

This *feels* rather odd to me, however I haven't found any sources to verify it one way or another so the question is - is *high school* allowed in BrE?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Education_in_England#Schools_and_stages mentions *High school* in "State funded schools" at the same level as *secondary school* however the article left me non the wiser...

Comment: Secondary school is the usual term for 11-18 yr-olds.

Comment: Similar to this recent [ELU question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/502063/what-is-a-secondary-school-graduate-called). In UK, we do not have "high school" as a generic type of school. Some schools have that in their name though, or as the linked table seems to show, be used internally to represent the section of the school.

Comment: Agree with @Weather here, definitely think that wiki article is dubious though! I went to a privately funded school which had High School in the name and was reception - 6th form. Plus I went to a different boarding school for "secondary school" which also does not follow that table on the wiki page!

Comment: I have never heard "high school" for an English school except in the titles of certain schools: "My secondary school is called X High School".  If a British person  says "high school" I understand them to be speaking of something in the US.   However I believe there are regional variations, and perhaps it's used in Scotland.